# basic form validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This simple form validation is not working and it's irritating me. Please let me know what is the problem. I have been trying to find a bug for almost two hours but can't find it. Please help me.

Take a look at code:

```js
function validate()
{
  if( $("#full_name").val() == "" )
  {
    alert( "Please provide your name!" );
    $("#full_name").focus() ;
    return false;
  }

  if( $("#email").val() == "")
  {
    alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
    $("#email").focus() ;
    return false;
  }
  
  if( $("#message").val() == "" )
  {
    alert( "Please Enter Message" );
    return false;
  }
  return( true );
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <h2> Contact Us </h2>
  <form  name="c_form" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return(validate());">
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" placeholder="Full Name">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>
    <div class="input textarea">
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter Message Here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input button">
      <button id="button"> Send </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Well there was nothing wrong except no jquery added in the snippet.

Comment: move your script to header block, instead before body close.

Comment: @venkat7668 Should do the opposite man.

Comment: thnaks !it's working in a seprate file now

Comment: i move my seprate file from head tag to after body tag

Comment: @MangeshShelke If your issue has already been solved, please mark any answer as accepted. If you have doubts on how to do it, just refer to this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235 thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not using HTML5's native "required" attribute? Nowadays, most browsers will happily interpret it without problems. If you want to support older browsers, just use a library like [h5validate](http://ericleads.com/h5validate/), but (please) keep your html clean.

Take a look on the same form using those attributes. No JS, no DIV containers, just plain native Html:

```css
input, textarea {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h2> Contact us without JS </h2>
<form name="c_form" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Enter Message Here" required></textarea>
    <button type="submit"> Send </button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanx i appreciate this

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes and it works. The following snippet:

1. Include jQuery.
2. Add all the contents inside `$(function () {})`.

```js
function validate ()
{
  if( $("#full_name").val() == "" )
  {
    alert( "Please provide your name!" );
    $("#full_name").focus() ;
    return false;
  }

  if( $("#email").val() == "")
  {
    alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
    $("#email").focus() ;
    return false;
  }
  
  if( $("#message").val() == "" )
  {
    alert( "Please Enter Message" );
    return false;
  }
  return( true );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <h2> Contact Us </h2>
  <form  name="c_form" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return(validate());">
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" placeholder="Full Name">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>
    <div class="input textarea">
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter Message Here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input button">
      <button id="button"> Send </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you actually did so the person who asked the answer can learn from their mistakes? As opposed to just pasting the fixed code.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhh i realize that it was a silly mistake i didn't include jquery

Comment: What's the source of the new script file and the HTML file. Can you post them too? If you post in JSBin, it would be perfect to read.

Answer (score 0):

I added an id of "c_form" to your html and removed the onsubmit property and used the following javascript code, which seemed to work. The key is calling ev.preventDefault();

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#c_form").submit(validate);
});

function validate(ev)
{
  if( $("#full_name").val() == "" )
  {
    alert( "Please provide your name!" );
    $("#full_name").focus() ;
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  if( $("#email").val() == "")
  {
    alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
    $("#email").focus() ;
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  if( $("#message").val() == "" )
  {
    alert( "Please Enter Message" );
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```